# FileManager.Enumerator running for ever when Searching for Files in a Drive

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nsfilemanager

I'm using the following code to search for files within Sub-Directories

```
let enumerator = try FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants])!.allObjects

self.fileArray = enumerator.filter { filterExtensions.contains(($0 as! URL).pathExtension) } as! [URL]
```

When the User Selects a Drive Containing Large number of Directories and Files,the enumerator keeps running for ever.It does not stop.In other cases the code works fine.

Comment: How many files are on that drive? If you do a `find /Volumes/YourDrive` on the command line, how long does it take?

Comment: @MartinR Im currently checking that... the drive contains windows installation.

Comment: @MartinR The command is still running ... taking too much time

Comment: Which means that there are *many* files to enumerate. You cannot expect the Swift code to do magic.

Comment: @MartinR Yes... more than 6 minutes in my stop watch..

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @techno that is not the method that you were using. Btw If you want to make it faster the second time include `[isRegularFileKey]` to the includingPropertiesForKeys and use the method I posted. Btw this might make it slower than without it but this will cache that info from the urls

Comment: @LeoDabus Have you seen the answer Martin had posted ?

Comment: Yes but as I said you should use resourceValues

Comment: @LeoDabus I think I will keep the old code(yours),since the issue is not with the code itself.Btw why did Martin delete his answer,currently I'm using his code.

Comment: Probably because you told him that it was actually slower than your previous code

Comment: try passing `[.isRegularFileKey]` to the includingPropertiesForKeys and time it

Comment: run it a second time and time again and let me know the results

Comment: then close your app open again and try without passing anu key to  includingPropertiesForKeys parameter and time it again. Once you finish it let me know the duration of each

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks .. but I will keep your old code... It just works fine ...

Comment: Anyway I am just curios about how long would them take. If you dont mind

Comment: @LeoDabus I will check and get back to you :)